# evitar o timeout no Swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

estou a utilizar o swiftmailer  e o throttler para enviar emails , o problema é que o browser faz timeout pois o throttler faz algumas pausas para manter o envio dentro dos limites (5 emails por minuto) , acho que o script continua a executar , será isto um problema? existe forma de evitar o timeout ?

```
// Use AntiFlood to re-connect after 100 emails
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(50));

// And specify a time in seconds to pause for (30 secs)
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(50, 30));



// Rate limit to 100 emails per-minute
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin(
  5, Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin::MESSAGES_PER_MINUTE
));

// Rate limit to 10MB per-minute
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin(
  1024 * 1024 * 10, Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin::BYTES_PER_MINUTE
```

Comment: Já verifique o tempo de timeout no php.ini ? Ou tentou utilizar a função `set_time_limit(0);` ?

Comment: sim já tentei isso ! o timeout no php.ini é geral e como o script faz muitas pausas nao gostava de ir por aí ...

Comment: Você pode setar pelo código também com `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` fazendo que não tenha limite

Comment: tentei mas sem resultado ..timeout na mesma

Comment: A função ini_set, define o valor de uma configuração, com ela, você consegue alterar a configuração por código

Comment: obrigado guilherme...tentei isso no script mas fez timeout na mesa

Comment: Tb aumenteio o maxexectime no cpanel mas tb deu timeout